# What does module type esnext means in tsconfig.json file?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have upgraded angular from version 8 to version 9.
In the migration process of angular, my tsconfig.json file come up with new property, i.e "module":"esnext". In the previous version of angular I did not have property like this. Can anybody please tell me.

Comment: Why would it increase the bundle size? The components were already included in the bundle. Entry component does not mean lazy loaded.

Comment: There is a difference between dynamically created and lazy loaded components : these components always have been included in the main bundle of the application.

Comment: We use declarations array in the app.module.ts file for declaring our component, but if particular component is not part of imperative component loading than that component would not be part of bundling. So that way I am asking.

Comment: Components defined in EntryComponents array are dynamic components not lazy loaded components. Means these are part of main bundle. With Angular 9 coming in and Ivy as the new rendering engine, all the components would be considered as entering components and do not necessarily need to specified inside the entryComponents array.